How can you make money with just an idea?
What should you do if you have an idea and a strategy, but not enough capital?
For me, business is about creating new products to offer to those who need them. Products can be divided into two types: services and goods.
Ways to solve this problem:
Raise capital from family, banks, or financial companies.
Based on the idea, find the smallest niche to generate profit, then accumulate them.
Call for investment.
Sell the strategy to those who need it.
"Successful people always have their own way." This saying is true, but its relevance to each of us is often rare. For me, as long as there is a "secret, formula, and benefit," it will create a unique mindset. Success will come if we persevere.
Starting from a low point, I believe you should not set your goals too high. Let future generations continue to pursue that dream.

Ideas are worth nothing, and come along all the time. Businesses are based on capital and hard work, not on ideas.

There are companies that will help you. But they are not motivated to give you an honest opinion of your idea. They will take money from you whether or not your idea is good.

First, if you are employed, read your contract; if you are a student check with the school's lawyers. Your employer or school may already own your idea, or have right of first refusal, especially if you are a "knowledge worker." If so, talk to them about what that process looks like.
If you do own the idea, it may be patentable, talk to a lawyer about that. You should do a patent search anyway to make sure your idea isn't already patented. This may also determine that the idea is "obvious to a practitioner", in which case its value drops precipitously.
Then talk to the lawyer about drawing up a non-disclosure agreement that you can ask folks to sign before you divulge your idea.
Then work up materials to market your idea with, from literature to presentations. Separate the presenting the problem from disclosing the solution, so people can look at the first to decide whether they are willing to sign the NDA and look at the second.
Then go out and try to find someone interested in licensing or buying the idea, or willing to fund your attempt to bring it to market in exchange for part ownership, or something of that sort. Expect this to be extremely difficult for any complicated idea, and hard even for simple ones. Note that nobody is likely to be interested in your just saying there is an opportunity; they want you to show that you have a solution, and one that will generate more profit, more reliably, than the many other things they could invest in.
At some point along here you may want to hire someone, under the NDA, to help you make a prototype and estimate what real costs are likely to be to bring this to market.
Yes, it's an uphill battle with no guaranteed payoff. Only you can decide how much effort you are willing to put into it and what you are willing to negotiate for. In general, if you aren't willing to "bet the farm" on your idea others won't either.
Good luck.
